# Do Bigquery Partition decorators with snapshot change with query parameters?

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I used

```
“SELECT title, COUNT(*)
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@1390581599000$0-of-3]
GROUP BY title”
```

and then used

```
“SELECT author
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@1390581599000$0-of-3]
GROUP BY author”
```

Am I guaranteed that both of these are run on the same dataset? Or is there no such guarantee since the number of shards used depends on the columns selected (due to ColumnIO storage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters are not affecting the dataset.

So running different queries on the same "snapshots" reads the same data.